# Django Error "Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax "

Tags: django, syntax

I'm creating an django app via this tutorial 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/
I'm trying to access admin page but it display this error which I don't know how to fix.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax (views.py, line 34)Request Method: GET 
Request URL: http://cat.pythonanywhere.com/admin/ 
Django Version: 1.3.5 
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError 
Exception Value: Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax (views.py, line 34) 
Exception Location: /home/cat/mysite/myapp/urls.py in <module>, line 2 
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi 
 Python Version: 2.7.3 
Python Path: ['/var/www',
```

my  views.py  are :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse ,HttpResponseRedirect
from mysite.myapp.models import Poll
from django.http import Http404
from django.template import Context, loader
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from polls.models import Choice, Poll

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the poll index.")

def detail(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at poll %s." % poll_id)

def results(request, poll_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at the results of poll %s." % poll_id)

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render(request, 'myapp/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp:results', args=(p.id,))))


def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
    context = Context({
    'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))



def detail(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'myapp/detail.html', {'poll': poll})
def results(request, poll_id):
    poll = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    return render(request, 'myapp/results.html', {'poll': poll})
```

Line 34 is here

```
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp:results', args=(p.id,))))
```

Can you please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('results', args=p.id))
```